# No module named 'encodings' with django3

Tags: python-3.6, mod-wsgi, django-3.0, centos8

already running a django program at CentOS7 daily.
I want move centos7 to be centos8.

I'm trying CentOS8. this is wsgi setting.

```
# dnf -y install python3-mod_wsgi
# vi /etc/httpd/conf.d/python3_wsgi.conf
```

this is new file. write into the new file.

```py
WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi /var/www/html/test_wsgi.py
```

```py
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    html = '<html>\n' \
           '<body>\n' \
           '<div style="width: 100%; font-size: 40px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center;">\n' \
           'WSGI TEST PAGE\n' \
           '</div>\n' \
           '</body>\n' \
           '</html>\n'.encode("utf-8")
    response_header = [('Content-type','text/html')]
    start_response(status,response_header)
    return [html]
```

```
# systemctl restart httpd
```

url input to chrome http://153.127.13.226/test_wsgi.
OK! It works! with wsgi!

but create django project with venv then not works one.

url input to chrome http://153.127.13.226/test_wsgi.
chrome is ... oh no! 503!

```
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.
```

venv directory is...

```
# python -c 'import sys; print(sys.prefix)'
  /home/op/venv
```

django project is...

```
# tree /var/www/html
/var/www/html
├ index.html
├ test_wsgi.py
└  testproject
    ├ manage.py
    └  testproject
        ├ __init__.py
        ├ asgi.py
        ├ settings.py
        ├ urls.py
        └  wsgi.py
```

```
WSGIDaemonProcess test_app python-path=/var/www/html/testproject python-home=/home/op/venv
WSGIProcessGroup test_app
WSGIScriptAlias /test_wsgi /var/www/html/testproject/testproject/wsgi.py
<Directory /var/www/html/testproject>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

error log is... it seems to endless.

```
# tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log
```

```
Current thread 0x00007f65e9c55900 (most recent call first):
[Mon Mar 23 21:13:57.702501 2020] [core:notice] [pid 26583:tid 140075690449152] AH00052: child pid 7780 exit signal Aborted (6)
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I already search stack over flow but not resolve yet.
I think it's a bit more, but I got stack over flow.

Comment: I think at Offce I maybe forgot Loadmodule . . .?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! I was solve!
but I did many time OS reset.
The error did not reproduce.

Probably the cause is 'SELinux'
Now, I don't know what was the cause, so I will introduce the final setting contents and the url that summarizes the process (I'm sorry, Japanese language)

django project name: mysite

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /var/www/html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py36.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi_app python-home=/var/www/html/venv python-path=/var/www/html/mysite
WSGIProcessGroup wsgi_app
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi
```

process: https://qiita.com/YoshitakaOkada/items/a75f664846c8c8bbb1e1#%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%83%9F%E3%83%83%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF